# 0(Zero) name folder not created on FTP

Tags: php, html, laravel, ftp

I’m trying to create subdirectories inside 0(zero) name folder using ftp_mksubdirs() using php, but subdirectories not created inside 0(zero) folder, subdirectories created parallel to 0(zero) folder.

Im trying to create folders using ftp_mksubdirs using php, my subdirectory path is /0/hv/ygggei/5666.
If I create 0 folder manually then hv/ygggei/5666 directory created parallel to 0 folder using ftp_mksubdirs. But I want to create hv/ygggei/5666 this path inside 0 folder. How using php?

```
$base_path = "/test/";
$sub_directories = "/0/tr/trfec24r/4242";

ftp_mksubdirs($ftp_conn, $base_path, $sub_directories)

   public static function ftp_mksubdirs($ftpcon,$ftpbasedir,$ftpath){
       @ftp_chdir($ftpcon, $ftpbasedir); // /var/www/uploads
       $parts = array_filter(explode('/',$ftpath)); // 2013/06/11/username
       foreach($parts as $part){
          if(!@ftp_chdir($ftpcon, $part)){
             ftp_mkdir($ftpcon, $part);
             //ftp_chmod($ftpcon, 0775, $part);
             ftp_chdir($ftpcon, $part);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code in your question

Comment: Question updated. Please check

Comment: Don't know if they are just copy errors here on SO but you have at least 2 typos: 
 1) `$sub_directories` is a string, and you are missing quotes around the value`"/0/tr/trfec24r/4242"` 2) The same line is missing a semi-colon at the end `;`.  If you are having problems, why would you not want to see any error messages?  The `@` suppresses errors, so if those commands are failing with some useful info telling you the problem ... you don't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the string `"0"` is also considered false, so `array_filter` will filter it.

I think you don't need to use `array_filter` here, just pass `"0/tr/trfec24r/4242"`(without the heading slash) to the function.

If you can't change the input, you can also trim it:

```
$sub_directories = trim($sub_directories, '/');
```

Or use a custom filter function:

```
$parts = array_filter(explode('/',$ftpath), fn($p) => $p !== '');
```